# Using ERC721 or ERC1155

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, contract-design, evm

I was thinking of a case where each uri is set upon mint.
The mint function takes in an amount to mint and a corresponding number of uri in an array.
Then as the tokenID is increased, the current tokenID is is set to the uri in the array.
User mints 2 items, token id of first item is 1 and second item is 2
The uri given as [uri1, uri2] is then assigned, 1 to uri1 and 2 to uri2
When the tokenURI is called, with tokenID argument, instead of concatenating a base uri with tokenid, it returns the uri from the mapping perhaps.
(Id=> uri) token

tokenURI(1) returns token[1] =uri1

I wonder if it’s possible with the current protocols in place for ERC721

Thank you for your opinions

Comment: I guess your mint function can receive these parameters ans ERC721 can mint with new URI each time. ERC1155 is less convenient about the URI. Did you try implementing it?